# Installing Cython on Windows 7

Tags: python, cython

I am trying to install Cython on a computer running Windows 7. I have installed
MinGW and added it to path. I have also created the distutil.cfg-file, as is described in other threads.

When i write

```
setup.py install --compiler=mingw32
```

at the command prompt I get the error message

```
error: command 'gcc' failed: No such file or directory
```

The MinGW\bin-directory does contain a file called gcc, but this doesn't help.

What do I do about this?

Comment: This is the sort of error you'd get if gcc wasn't on your path. Are you sure you've added MinGW's bin directory to your path? If so, try restarting your terminal. The path used in a command prompt session is the one that was set when the session was started, so maybe you just need to be in a terminal that is using your current path.

Comment: The path to gcc is C:\MinGW\bin\gcc and C:\MinGW\bin is in my path.

I tried to run it again today, and setup.py won't even start. It just says "error: option --compiler not recognized".

Comment: I tried again using only "setup.py install". This time it fails in the same manner it did yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a space before c:\mingw\bin in path. When it was removed it worked.